# Multithreading for loop in C

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, multidimensional-array, pthreads

Wondering why dividing a for loop into two threads like this would slow my performance down by almost double? I'm running on a dual-core processor.

Normal loop  (1.78 s):

```
int var;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j=0; j < p; j++){
               var = 0;
               for (k=0; k < m; k++)
                       var = i + k;
        }
```

Divided loop  (2.53 s):

```
pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, A, NULL);
pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, B, NULL);
for (i=0; i < 2; i++) pthread_join(tid[i],NULL) == 0;
```

...

```
void * A(void *arg)
{
    int i, j, k, var;
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        for (j=0; j < p; j++)
        {
               var = 0;
               for (k=0; k < m; k++)
                    var = i + k;
        }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void * B(void *arg)
{
      int i, j, k, var;
      for (i = n/2; i < n; i++)
            for (j=0; j < p; j++)
            {
                 var = 0;
                 for (k=0; k < m; k++)
                     var = i + k;
            }
      pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to memory accesses? I'd try removing memory accesses from the loop and then go back and test my single-threaded and double-threaded loops to see if there is a speed increase, then add back memory reads and benchmark, then add back writes and benchmark? I don't have experience with this; it's just how I would approach the troubleshooting.

Comment: Actually first I would wonder if it was even using both cores - what OS are you running on, does it split single-process threads across cores, under what conditions, etc.

Comment: "same performance" means it ran in 1 second for both? or half an hour?  or?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an error in code. Row `c[n/2][0..p]` is calculated in each thread, and if by chance it happens at the same time you'll get wrong results there. In thread B value `i` should start from `n/2 + 1`.

Comment: Ok, so I just ran the same loops without the arrays and just basic arithmetic. I'm getting the same proportions: 1.78 s for the normal and 2.53 s for the two-threaded method. Using OSX 10.7 (Lion). @Macattack: I don't think that's correct.

Comment: How did you compile, and with which compiler (in addition to OS info as already asked)?  Can you provide an SSCCE?

Comment: gcc loops.c -o loops -lpthread -lrt, using gcc version 4.4.7

Comment: Can you post the code that is spawning both threads?

Comment: Ok, I modified the code because the array accessing is irrelevant and I included the creating and joining of threads.

Comment: May I suggest using OpenMP for such an application? It can significantly reduce the amount of work you have to do for simple loops like this and is supported by most compilers off the bat. Of course, if you want the threads to do completely different things then pthreads is the way to go.

Comment: With no optimization (gcc with `-O0` or no `-O` flag) the `n/2` will be computed every time.  Won't hurt `B` but `A` will certainly be a bit slower.  The rest should be similar though, so that doesn't explain all of it.

Comment: I am curious what happens if instead of a single loop you call function A and then function B in your single threaded test rather than the calls to pthread_create().  Also I am curious as to what happens with really large values of n so that the single threaded version runs for tens of seconds.

Comment: How are you measuring the time? Additionally, if you're replying to somebody's comment, please [tag the person](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply) so that they will be notified.

Comment: @AnishRam...got it working (see explanation below)...will do in the future. Using timeval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using global variables (i,j,k,x,y,z,etc..) for iterating through the loop. I didn't show that in the examples so you wouldn't have known. That added a great deal of overhead apparently. Now it is working properly with the local variables for each thread.

Comment: Yes, that explains quite a lot ... and, I hope, tells you why the [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754) is a good idea. :-)

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question as it just says that with a code change there was a difference in software behavior with no explanation as to why.  What is the source of the overhead you think was added?  In the source code of the question the loop variables i, j, and k are all local as is the variable var.  The variables n, p, and m are not defined in the functions so I would assume are global.  How were those global variables defined?

Comment: n, p, and m were macros. The explanation I am not entirely sure of. If I were to guess, it would be that global variables are not allocated to the stack, which requires a longer access time because there is no pointer pointing to them...? It is a longer search.